# Why is there no definition for MaskPredicate::operator=(const MaskPredicate&) in OpenCV?

Tags: opencv

https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/features2d/src/keypoint.cpp

The declaration of the function is in line 154.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making the assignment operator private and unimplemented is a popular way of ensuring that assigments cannot be made (i.e. the compilation will fail).

It is also common to find the same thing done with copy constructors, (although not in this case) so that an object is not copyable.

The underlying reason is usually to do with the internal implementation of the class, which will have been decided by the designers. For example, it makes sense to ensure that a singleton is not copied or assigned, or that an object that contains pointers to other objects is not shallow-copied, causing potential problems at destruction.

In this particular case, the assignment operator was removed as a fix to [OpenCV - Bug #419](http://code.opencv.org/issues/419).